# Не могу посчитать элементы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу подсчитать элементы для завершенных и оставшихся задач

```
import requests,os,json,datetime
try:
    responsed_tasks=json.loads(requests.get('https://json.medrating.org/todos').text)
except:
    print('Не удалось получить задачи')
try:
    responsed_users=json.loads(requests.get('https://json.medrating.org/users').text)
except:
    print('Не удалось получить пользователей')
try:
    os.mkdir('c://Tasks')
except FileExistsError:
    print('Директория уже существует')
try:
    for user in responsed_users:
        create_file=open(fr"C://Tasks//{user['username']}.txt",'w')
        time=datetime.datetime.now()
        time=time.replace(microsecond=0)
        write_file=create_file.write(
            f"Отчет для {user['company']['name']}.\n"
            f"{user['name']} <{user['email']}> {time}\n"
            f"Всего задач: 20\n"
            f"\n"
            f"Завершенные задачи({}): \n"
            f"\n"
            f"Оставшиеся задачи({}): \n")

except KeyError:
    pass
```

Comment: Почему не можете подсчитать? Выбивает ошибку?

Comment: уже решил, спасибо за внимание

Answer (score 0):

Просто надо добавить счетчик

```
import requests,os,json,datetime
try:
    responsed_tasks=json.loads(requests.get('https://json.medrating.org/todos').text)
except:
    print('Не удалось получить задачи')
try:
    responsed_users=json.loads(requests.get('https://json.medrating.org/users').text)
except:
    print('Не удалось получить пользователей')
try:
    os.mkdir('c://Tasks')
except FileExistsError:
    print('Директория уже существует')
try:
    count = 0
    tasks = len(responsed_users)
    for user in responsed_users:
        create_file=open(fr"C://Tasks//{user['username']}.txt",'w')
        time=datetime.datetime.now()
        time=time.replace(microsecond=0)
        count += 1
        write_file=create_file.write(
            f"Отчет для {user['company']['name']}.\n"
            f"{user['name']} <{user['email']}> {time}\n"
            f"Всего задач: 20\n"
            f"\n"
            f"Завершенные задачи({count}): \n"
            f"\n"
            f"Оставшиеся задачи({tasks - count}): \n")

except KeyError:
    pass
```